# How to get animators in an AnimatorSet (NOT AnimationSet) to share interpolator?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an `AnimatorSet` which consists of two ValueAnimators that I am playing sequentially. I would like for the ValueAnimators to share a single `OvershootInterpolator`. **Animation**Set has an API for setting this. However I cannot find an equivalent in **Animator**Set. If I call `myAnimatorSet.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator())` it sets a separate interpolator on each child animation. Does anyone know of a way that I can achieve what I'm looking to do?

Comment: see AnimatorSet.java source,  go to method start() and see what is done with mInterpolator field

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to? It sets `mInterpolator` on each child node separately. I want them to share an interpolator.

Comment: so they share the same interpolator,  or i misunderstood the word share?

Comment: They are each interpolated separately with this method. So if I set a single OvershootInterpolator on the AnimatorSet, the first child node accelerates and overshoots, then the second node accelerates and then overshoots. I want the first child to start accelerating, then the second to continue accelerating where the first one left off and then overshoot at the end. AnimationSet has a constructor `AnimationSet (boolean shareInterpolator)` which achieves this as well as a corresponding XML attribute. But I need this to work for an AnimationSet.

Comment: sorry but i don't get it,  OvershootInterpolator interpolates 0 (starting value) as 0 and 1 (final value) as 1 (interpolating to something  > 1 just before the end) so the end interpolated values is always 1 so how the next interpolator could start from something that is != 0? maybe there is something you misinterpret?

Comment: An overshoot interpolator overshoots at the end ( > 1) and then bounces back. If two animations in a set share an interpolator, only the second animation will overshoot and bounce back. In the current API for setting the interpolator on each node separately, the first animation will overshoot, then the second animation will overshoot.

Comment: i don't see such behavior, see: http://pastebin.com/f41zJRYC or maybe i missed something?

Comment: That is an ANIMATION set, not an ANIMATOR set. But yes that is exactly what I am looking to do with an AnimatorSet. I need an [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) for two [ValueAnimators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html)

Comment: "If two animations in a set share an interpolator, only the second animation will overshoot and bounce back" i posted a code using an AnimationSet sharing the interpolator and as you can see BOTH animations it the set overshoot, so i dont really dont know what you want to achieve

Comment: Ah, okay I see what you're saying.

Comment: so probably there is XY problem here... :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The paste bin is gone... what... was the solution here? 